# in page links not working/inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

See http://www.collegeanswerz.com/university-of-pittsburgh/social-life/kids/is-it-easy-to-make-friends.  When you click on different questions, I want it to link to a convenient place on the page (right above the grey backgrounded question description).

Sometimes it scrolls too far down.  Sometimes it links to the top of 'University of Pittsburgh', when it should be linking to the actual (grey outlined) question.  It's actually working on my development environment, but not working in production.  `<a id="top"></a>` is in the right spot in production (I checked view source).  Any ideas about what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the extra `<a>` element. Just add an `id` attribute to the grey box (like `id="top"`) and the anchor will jump to the position.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLDAt/)

### Edit

Add a style to your anchor that puts it on the desired position like

```
#top {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:130px;
}
```

Comment: I've been messing around... and that works, but the subsequent part of the page that loads is such that I'd rather a little bit of white space at the top of the page (don't really know how to explain this, but it doesn't look good when there is zero white space).  So I tried to alter some margin-top stuff, but it's messing my code up.  Do you know why it isn't working when I use the extra <a> element?  Because if you do, that'd be an easier fix.  It is working in my development environment with the extra <a> element.

Comment: Your `<a>` is on an completely strange position. It is after the disquss. It should be before `<div id="question_sub" ...>...</div>`. I would replace the `<a>` with a `<div>` as well.

Comment: Yea, you're right about that.  I was just messing around in different places because I was having trouble.  I changed it to before `<div id="question_sub` now.  Now there are two problems: 1) the space is a little more than I'd like it to be, 2) sometimes it starts off linking to the right place, and then scrolls halfway down the page without me doing anything.

Comment: The About College section works great.  I want it to work like that.

Comment: Try another anchor name. Maybe disquss does strange things.

Comment: I changed the id from top to topp, and that seems to have created an even bigger space.  Although it doesn't seem to be scrolling down automatically now.  (I updated the site so you could see)

Comment: The space problem can be solved if you put the anchor to a positin that is deeper than the beginning of `<div id="question_sub" ...>...</div>`. Maybe inside it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34851/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-christopher-perrin)